# function does not work as expected in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a problem with the following script:

```
function select_run {
    clear
    if [ -d ./folder1 ]; then
        echo "folder1 exist"
    exit
    else
        echo "folder1 doesnt exist"
        mkdir folder1
        select_run
    fi
}
```

So the question here is that after the script create the **folder1** which it doesn't exist and after I tried to call the same function in order to verify if the folder exists, but it does not work, because the script always shows me the part regarding `else` command, I don't know why.

Comment: for me your code is working fine

Comment: `mkdir -p` will create a directory only if it doesn't exist, if that is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your function begins by running `clear`, which means that you never see the error message that `mkdir` is giving you. If you remove that line, you'll see what the problem is.